# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable , when called for time()

Tags: typeerror

start = time()

```
input_list = input_list_def(args.motor_rate, args.radius, args.weight, args.height, args.time)
output_list, unit = error_check_inputs(input_list)
weight, height, radius, rpm_value, time = output_list['weight'], output_list['height'], output_list['radius'], \
                                          output_list['rpm_value'], output_list['time']

weight, height, radius, rpm_value, time_in_hrs = unit_conversion(unit, weight, height, radius, rpm_value, time)
#execute(MET_mph, args.motor_rate, args.radius, args.weight, args.height, args.time)

end = time()
print(end-start)
```

**Error**

end = time()

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: Somewhere above this, you've set a variable called `time` and stored a `float` in it. Just rename that variable/reload your REPL.

Comment: Actually, it's right here: `. . ., time = output_list[ . . .`. Rename that variable.

Comment: Oh.....thank you very much really. I'm new to this stuff. @ Carcigenicate